# How I can build TFS 2015 project by console application?

Tags: c#, tfs-2015

I want to build a project in TFS 2015, I want to use console application that will connect to TFS and build the specified project.

Comment: This question is too broad.  I'm not the one who downvoted you.

Comment: Do you have any issue during the build? Do you want to use XAML build or new build system?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to ask how to use TFS API to create a build definition and queue a build.

You can use TFS REST API to achieve your goal.

[Create a build definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#create-a-build-definition):

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version={version}
```

[Queue a build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build):

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version={version}
```

Comment: I want to build a project that is present in the TFS. I will use a console application. Using this console application I will connect to TfS. And then i will build a specific project that is present in the TFS using this console application. Not able to find any guidance in the above URL for that.